# T-SQL: get only rows which are after a row that meets some condition

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table of article's logs. I need to get all the articles which have only one log, or in case there are amount of logs more than 1: if an article has any log in status = 103, it's need to fetch only rows after this log, in other case all the logs. So from the following dataset I want to get only rows with Id 1383 and 284653.

| Id | Article | Version | StatusId | AddedDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1383 | 1481703 | 0 | 42 | 2011-11-25 09:23:42.000 |
| 284645 | 435545 | 1 | 41 | 2021-11-02 18:29:42.000 |
| 284650 | 435545 | 2 | 41 | 2021-11-02 18:34:58.000 |
| 284651 | 435545 | 2 | 103 | 2021-11-02 18:34:58.000 |
| 284653 | 435545 | 3 | 41 | 2021-11-02 18:38:33.000 |

Any ideas how to handle it properly ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use window functions here. A combination of a running `COUNT` and a windowed `COUNT` will do the trick

The benefit of using window functions rather than self-joins is that you only scan the base table once.

```sql
SELECT
  Id,
  Article,
  Version,
  StatusId,
  AddedDate
FROM (
    SELECT *,
      HasPrev103 = COUNT(CASE WHEN StatusId = 103 THEN 1 END) OVER
              (PARTITION BY Article ORDER BY AddedDate ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING),
      Has103 = COUNT(CASE WHEN StatusId = 103 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY Article),
      Count = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Article)
    FROM YourTable t
) t
WHERE (Has103 > 0 AND HasPrev103 > 0) OR Count = 1;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3134fe7d05c1dd4474f707e147a81f28)

Comment: There is one more condition mentioned in op

Comment: Thank you @Charlieface , it works fine. I see your point about scanning the table only once. Unfortunately in my case I have to convert it to my programming language script and I have some restrictions there (don't have an option to use partitions) so will use  Richard's approach below, but extremely appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE #Article (
    Id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    Article int NOT NULL,
    Version int NOT NULL,
    StatusId int NOT NULL,
    DateAdded datetime NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Article (Id, Article, Version, StatusId, DateAdded)
VALUES
    (1383,  1481703,    0,  42,     '2011-11-25 09:23:42.000'),
    (284645, 435545,    1,  41 ,    '2021-11-02 18:29:42.000'),
    (284650, 435545,    2,  41 ,    '2021-11-02 18:34:58.000'),
    (284651, 435545,    2,  103,    '2021-11-02 18:34:58.000'),
    (284653, 435545,    3,  41 ,    '2021-11-02 18:38:33.000')

SELECT *
FROM #Article a
    LEFT JOIN (
        -- Get articles that appear only once.
        SELECT Article
        FROM #Article
        GROUP BY Article
        HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    ) AS o
        ON a.Article = o.Article
    LEFT JOIN (
        -- Get the 103s and their corresponding date.
        SELECT Article, DateAdded
        FROM #Article
        WHERE StatusId = 103
    ) AS s
        ON a.Article = s.Article AND s.DateAdded < a.DateAdded
WHERE o.Article IS NOT NULL OR (s.Article IS NOT NULL AND a.DateAdded > s.DateAdded)

DROP TABLE #Article
```

Comment: The second subquery needs to be `SELECT Article, MIN(DateAdded) AS DateAdded ... GROUP BY Article` in case thre is more than one 103 for the Article.